# pd.to_datetime doesn't work with %a format

Tags: pandas, datetime

I'm having a trouble with pandas to_datetime function
When I call the function in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(['Wed', 'Thu', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Fri'], format='%a')
```

I get this result:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1900-01-01', '1900-01-01', '1900-01-01', '1900-01-01',
               '1900-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I don't know why pandas don't recognize the correct format.

I want get a datetime object which has the right day independently the month or year

Comment: You did not pass the year month ...

Comment: @YOBEN_S I dont care year and month, just I want the day.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense, it's totally ambiguous. I could give you a list of dates [January 7 1920, June 4 2020, ...] and that would be perfectly fine  for [Wed, Thu, ...]. If you need a numeric representation why not use a simple dict that maps like `{'Wed': 2, 'Thu': 3, ...}`? Writing 7 mappings is manageable.

Comment: @ALollz yes, you are right, but I'm curious about why this dont work haha. You can see the days are same (01) for all cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a pandas issue but with datetime in python.

Here is the best documentation I can find why '1900-01-01' [Python Datetime Technical Details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail).

Note:

> For the datetime.strptime() class method, the default value is
>   1900-01-01T00:00:00.000: any components not specified in the format
>   string will be pulled from the default value.

Basically, it could be any Monday, Tuesday (day of the week name) in the month of Jan 1900. Therefore, it is ambiguous, thus returning the default value of 1900-01-01T00:00:00.000. If you put in a day of the month then that date is determinant using the given defaults of Jan 1900, so using strptime with 1 and %d does lead to the date of 1900-Jan-01 00:00:00.000 and 2 with %d will lead to 1900-Jan-02 00:00:00.000, just using Mon or Monday, is not determinant to a datetime.

This is my interpretation of the documentation and the issue you are experiencing.